# Tensorflow: Weird behaviour in dynamic_rnn: printing input changes the output

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Noticed a strange strange behaviour in the `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`: 
given the script below, with random seed set (line 7), just adding `print training_data * 2` or any other number, will change the outcome of the training. Does anyone has an idea why this happens? Try it yourself by adding/removing that line

Note that given that the random seed is set, when the training data is not printed the outcome of the training is always the same, and when it's printed it's always different with same costs, no matter what `n` is.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

tf.set_random_seed(0x1111)

def generate_data(dataset_len=10, vec_len=5):
    assert vec_len < dataset_len
    def generate_datapoint(period, vec_length, datapont_len):
        indexes = numpy.array([i % period for i in range(datapont_len)])
        vectors = numpy.zeros((datapont_len, vec_length))
        vectors[numpy.arange(datapont_len), indexes] = 1
        return vectors
    return [generate_datapoint(n % vec_len + 1, vec_len, n) for n in range(10, 10 + dataset_len)]

dataset = generate_data(20, 7)

# input and output are shifted by one
datapoints = [datapoint[:-1].astype('float32') for datapoint in dataset]
output_datapoints = [datapoint[1:].astype('float32') for datapoint in dataset]

print "test and training data loaded"

training_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, datapoints[0].shape[1]]) # Number of examples, sequence_len, vector_len
expected_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, output_datapoints[0].shape[1]])

lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(50)
multi_lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[lstm_cell] * 2, state_is_tuple=True)

print training_data * 2

lstm_output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_lstm_cell, training_data, dtype=tf.float32)
output = tf.layers.dense(lstm_output, output_datapoints[0].shape[1], use_bias=False)

cost = tf.reduce_mean((output - expected_output)**2)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

for epoch in range(100):
    epoch_costs = []
    for inp, out in zip(datapoints, output_datapoints):
        o, c, _opt = sess.run([output, cost, optimizer],
                        feed_dict={training_data: [inp],
                                   expected_output: [out]})
        epoch_costs.append(c)
    print "Epoch ", str(epoch), numpy.mean(epoch_costs)
sess.close()
```

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using? The reproducer you've provided fails with `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 100 and 57 for [...]`.